# Magento 2: How add dropdown in admin form?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, adminhtml, adminform

I have set dropdown in form.xml like

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="options" xsi:type="string">Book\Flip\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Category</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
        <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">category</item>
        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">flip</item>
        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">category</item>
        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
```

and create model

```
namespace Book\Flip\Model\Category\Attribute\Source;

    class Category extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
    {
        protected $_optionsData;

        public function __construct(array $options)
        {
            $this->_optionsData = $options;
        }

        public function getAllOptions()
        {
            if ($this->_options === null) {
                $this->_options = [
                    ['value' => '1', 'label' => __('science')]
                ];
            }
            return $this->_options;
        }
    }
```

But in admin form it's shown a blank dropdown.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/147174)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/147174)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change **Category** class by following code:

```php
namespace Book\Flip\Model\Source;

class Category implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
    /**
     * Retrieve options array.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $result = [];

        foreach (self::getOptionArray() as $index => $value) {
            $result[] = ['value' => $index, 'label' => $value];
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve option array
     *
     * @return string[]
     */
    public static function getOptionArray()
    {
        return [1 => __('science')];
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve option array with empty value
     *
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $result = [];

        foreach (self::getOptionArray() as $index => $value) {
            $result[] = ['value' => $index, 'label' => $value];
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve option text by option value
     *
     * @param string $optionId
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOptionText($optionId)
    {
        $options = self::getOptionArray();

        return isset($options[$optionId]) ? $options[$optionId] : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: i get this error 

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory::argumentsResolver() must be of the type array, null given, called in /var/www/html/codility-magento-market-place/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php on line 206 and defined in /var/www/html/codility-magento-market-place/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php:172

Comment: How to pass block file in magento 2.3.1 @Sohel Rana

Answer (score 6):

I assume you found this out by now, but the xml in the form ui

```
<item name="options" xsi:type="string">Book\Flip\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Category</item>
```

belongs under **data** as a sibling of **config** not a child, and its *xsi:type* should be "object"

Like this

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Book\Flip\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Category</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
        <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">category</item>
        ...
```

I also was stuck on this issue for awhile until I figured out that bit.

Comment: I see this as the common way to specify a source model; however, is there documentation to support this? I am confused as to what this means for column `eav_attribute.source_model` -- moreover, the UI definition for a similar attribute, `landing_page`, does not have such arguments and yet it works. Looking for some authoritative answers.

Answer (score 4):

```
class category implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{ 
    //Below function is supposed to return options.
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return [
            ['value' => 1, 'label' => 'label1'],
            ['value' => 2, 'label' => 'label2']
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried your method but it does not seem to work. Please Update to 
```
public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return [
            ['value' => 1, 'label' => 'label1'],
            ['value' => 2, 'label' => 'label2']
        ];
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to add an extra select field to an already existing form not built with ui-components and if you need to apply to that field a custom model config source you can use this code:

```
         $fieldset->addField(
            'x_custom_slideshow',
            'select',
            [
                'name' => 'brand_custom_slideshow',
                'label' => __('Choose slideshow'),
                'title' => __('Choose slideshow'),
                'required' => false,
                'values' => $sliderConfig->toOptionArray()
            ]
        );
```

after you previuosly specified/loaded the model config class via contructor or via object manager for eg.

```
$sliderConfig = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Namespace\Slideshow\Model\Config\Source\Slideshow');
```

I hope this helps.