# Category attribute dropdown saying class doesnt exists

Tags: magento2

Here is my xml file for my custom category drop down

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<fieldset name="general">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">General Settings</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">0</item>
        </item>
    </argument>

        <field name="cat_front_label">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">XX\XX\Model\CategoryLabelDropdown</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Label</item>
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="33" xsi:type="string">33</item>
                        <item name="50" xsi:type="string">50</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

and here is my CategoryLabelDropdown in

> XX/model/CategoryLabelDropdown.php

```
namespace XX\XX\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;

class CategoryLabelDropdown implements OptionSourceInterface
{

    /**
     * Get options
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {

            $options = [
                [
                'label' => 'Test',
                'value' => '1',
                ],
                [
                'label' => 'Test2',
                'value' => '2',
                ]
            ];
        return $options;
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error

: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method XX\XX\Model\CategoryLabelDropdown::setAttribute()

Answer (score 0):

try below method

```
namespace XX\XX\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface;

class CategoryLabelDropdown implements ArrayInterface
{

    /**
     * Get options
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {

            $options = [
                [
                'label' => 'Test',
                'value' => '1',
                ],
                [
                'label' => 'Test2',
                'value' => '2',
                ]
            ];
        return $options;
    }
}
```

Comment: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method XX\XX\Model\CategoryLabelDropdown::setAttribute()

Comment: Still the same mate

Comment: Did you tried this solution? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156864/magento-2-how-add-dropdown-in-admin-form/156877

Comment: if i try that i get Class XX\XX\Model\CategoryLabelDropdown does not exist.. is there anywhere else i need to add it?

Comment: I think, you did some php errors..please double check your file

Comment: i now get Cannot declare class XX\XX\Model\Source\CategoryLabelDropdownValues, because the name is already in use even though that class doesnt exist anywhere else (this comes since i deleted geenrated folder)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change you xml code like this one.

```
<field name="cat_front_label" formElement="select">
     <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
         <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
             <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Label</item> 
         </item>
     </argument>
     <formElements>
          <select>
             <settings>
                 <options class="XX\XX\Model\CategoryLabelDropdown"/>
             </settings>
          </select>
     </formElements>
</field>
```

Comment: I get error Fatal error: Cannot declare class XX\XX\Model\Source\CategoryLabelDropdownValues, because the name is already in use in /domains/gaz.development.co.uk/http/app/code/XX/XX/Model/CategoryLabelDropdownValues.php on line 3

Comment: But that class does not exist ive tried the same thing with all sorts of random class names